# Java-Hibernate from List of values to multidimensional double arrays

Tags: java, hibernate, matlab, dynamic-arrays

With the following snippet I am trying to build from a List returned from Hibernate a multidimensional array , double[][]:

The `data` list gets to `makeSet`, the `makeSet` tries to return a `[][] double` array. The optimal, is that I don't know how many arrays should I have. So I tried calling `makeInnerSet` but unless I create a `new double[][] ix, iy` in the code, the code does not iterate well.

**Is there a way to know the columns of an array [][] ?**

**Perhaps is there another approach to the problem ?**

**It's mandatory to take back the scalar values of Hibernate and make them double[][] of what ever size. Any help ?**

```
List data = qry.list();
double[][] inputData = makeSet(data);

public double[] makeInnerSet(List data, double[] ix, int col ){
    int i = 0;
    Iterator<?> itr1 = data.listIterator();
    while (itr1.hasNext()) {
        Object[] result = (Object[]) itr1.next();
        if (result[col] != null) {
            double res1 = (Double) result[col];
            ix[i] = res1;
        }else{
            ix[i] = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return ix;
}
public double[][] makeSet(List data){
    Iterator<?> itr1 = data.listIterator();
    double[] ix = new double[data.size()];
    double[] iy = new double[data.size()];
    double[][] x = { makeInnerSet(data, iy,0), makeInnerSet(data, ix,1) };  
    return x;
}
```

**EDIT**
Well making making the code :

```
double[][] x = { 
            makeInnerSet(data, new double[data.size()],0), 
            makeInnerSet(data, new double[data.size()],1) 
            };
```

Half-found my answer...seconds later...
I certainly now don't need the ix, iy. But how do I take the number of columns in the List ?

Comment: `int columns = ((object[])data.first()).size()` ?

Comment: Firo, this seems to me kind of wird, you ask first() and then the size() which I can guess it will bring the length, not the width of the list in columns. But the main, is that the code produces error with this, in casting and some others also after trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all arrays in the list have the same size (because otherwise makeinnerset would bomb ,too):

```
int columns = ((Object[])data.first()).size()
```

the code gets the first array and get its size which should be the same for all arrays.